# How To change mouse Speed in c# using a Tack Bar

Tags: c#, forms

dose anyone know how i can change mouse speed based on a Track Bar in C# i have been looking around and cant seem to find anything about it any help helps

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using the interop services. Here is a basic example with just using numbers. You can add a slider that has a range of numbers and plug in to the code below. I tested this as working, so should be pretty easy.
find this in namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MouseSpeedSwitcher
{
    class Program
    {
        public const UInt32 SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071;

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern Boolean SystemParametersInfo(
            UInt32 uiAction, 
            UInt32 uiParam, 
            UInt32 pvParam,
            UInt32 fWinIni);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SystemParametersInfo(
                SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 
                0, 
                uint.Parse(args[0]), 
                0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Heres info on slider/trackbar https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.trackbar?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1